# How to use setState() to change NavigationBar icons?

Tags: flutter, uinavigationbar, setstate

I am trying to change the icon shape for each item of the following [custom navigationBr](https://pub.dev/packages/convex_bottom_bar) based on weather they are selected or not:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/home';

  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: currentIndex,
        children: screens,
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: ConvexAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
          onTap: (index) {
            setState() {
              currentIndex = index;
            }
          },
          style: TabStyle.fixed,
          items: [
            TabItem(
              icon: currentIndex == 0
                  ? Icons.local_fire_department
                  : Icons.local_fire_department_outlined,
              title: 'Contests',
            ),
            TabItem(
              icon: currentIndex == 1
                  ? Icons.remove_red_eye
                  : Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined,
              title: 'Reviews',
            ),
          TabItem(
             icon: currentIndex == 2
                 ? Icons.health_and_safety
                 : Icons.health_and_safety_outlined,
             title: 'Add New',
             ),
          ]),
      );
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I create such a behavior that when user chooses one of the nav bar options it's icon turns on and when the user chooses another item the icon changes to outlined icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code created local function `setState` instead of using existing `setState`

```
         onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              currentIndex = index;
            });
          },
```

Your code looks create new local function

```
setState(){
}
```

So that update is not happening here.

Comment: So how can I use the actual `setState()`?

Comment: First code works, just replace the `onTap` with my first block

Answer (score 1):

dev

I have fixed your problem actually the problem is that the state is not updating there. you have to use `onTabNotify` instead of `onTap` which will sort your issue.

I have also done 1 thing is that instead of updating the whole code I used stream so the only required widget will update. and for that, i have used the [rxdart: ^0.27.7](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart) version. please check the following code snippet.

```
import 'package:convex_bottom_bar/convex_bottom_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final BehaviorSubject<int> bottomBarIndex = BehaviorSubject<int>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<int>(
          stream: bottomBarIndex.stream,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
            return IndexedStack(
              index: snapshot.data,
              children: const [ContestsPage(), ReviewsPage(), AddNewPage()],
            );
          }),
      bottomNavigationBar: StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: bottomBarIndex.stream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
          return ConvexAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
            onTabNotify: (index) {
              bottomBarIndex.sink.add(index);
              return true;
            },
            items: [
              TabItem(
                icon: snapshot.data == 0 ? Icons.local_fire_department : Icons.local_fire_department_outlined,
                title: 'Contests',
              ),
              TabItem(
                icon: snapshot.data == 1 ? Icons.remove_red_eye : Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined,
                title: 'Reviews',
              ),
              TabItem(
                icon: snapshot.data == 2 ? Icons.health_and_safety : Icons.health_and_safety_outlined,
                title: 'Add New',
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ContestsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContestsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('ContestsPage'),
    );
  }
}

class ReviewsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReviewsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('ReviewsPage'),
    );
  }
}

class AddNewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AddNewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('AddNewPage'),
    );
  }
}
```

Please let me know if you still face any issue with this code.